# Angular 2 ContentChild Apply Html Attributes

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

I have a custom component that applies bootstrap form group to my form fields. In my component I have below properties:

```
import { Component, Input, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'form-field',
    template: `
            <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':(state && !state.valid && state.touched)}">
                <label *ngIf="label" [attr.for]="state.name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{label}}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <ng-content></ng-content>
                    <div *ngIf="state && !state.valid && state.errors && state.touched" class="help-block text-danger">
                        <span *ngIf="state.errors.required">{{label? label:'This field'}} is required</span>
                        <span *ngIf="state.errors.min">{{label? label:'Value'}} too small</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            `
})
export class FormFieldComponent{
    @Input()
    label: string;

    @ContentChild(NgControl) state;
}
```

And in my template I use my component like this:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
    <form-field label="First Name">
     <input ngControl="firstName" type="text">
    </form-field>
</form>
```

I was wondering is there any way to dynamically set the placeholder text for the control through my component?

I want the label to be set as placeholder of the input field i.e.

Comment: Where is the `<form>` element?

Comment: Please provide `.ts` and `.html` for child and parent components (at least parts relevant to your question)

Comment: I have updated the question, please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This directive is applied to all input elements that have a `ngControl` or `[ngControl]="..."` attribute. It sets the `placeholder` attribute on the element where it is applied.

It is made globally available using

```ts
bootstrap(App, [
  provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [InputLabel], multi: true})
])
```

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: ['[ngControl]']
})
export class InputLabel {
  @Input()
  @HostBinding('attr.placeholder') 
  label;

  constructor() {
    console.log('InputLabel');
  }
}
```

In the `FormField` component this directive is queried for and the label from the input is passed to the directive (in `ngOnChanges` or `ngAfterContentChecked` - basically the first occurence where `label` and `state` are available.

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'form-field',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class FormField {
  @Input() label: string;
  @ContentChild(InputLabel) state;

  ngOnChanges() {
    if(this.label && this.state) {
      this.state.label = this.label;
    }
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    if(this.label && this.state) {
      this.state.label = this.label;
    }
  }
}
```

This is just to demonstrate how its used:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
<form>      
  <form-field label="First Name">
    <input ngControl="firstName" type="text">
  </form-field>      
</form>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [FormField, FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class App {

  constructor(fb:FormBuilder) {
    this.name = 'Angular2 (Release Candidate!)'
    this.form = fb.group({firstName: [""]});
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/eSK15B5dAo1YyV5NUyb1?p=preview)

I choose this approach because I wasn't able to query by something else (`NgControl`, ...) and get a reference to the input element.

It's not necessary to provide the directive this way. It can also be provided like any other custom directive by adding it to `directives: [InputLabel]` on the `@Component()` decorator where it is used.

Comment: Thank you so much I am receiving duplicate identifier error while compiling InputLabel directive.I tried updating 
@Input() label;
@HostBinding('attr.placeholder') placeholder;
but it doesnt work

Comment: In visual studio while compiling, I get "Duplicate identifier 'label'" and red line is shown below the label in InputLabel directive. Should I update the line @HostBinding('attr.placeholder') label; to @HostBinding('attr.placeholder') placeholder; ?

Comment: Another thing, I am using @ContentChild(NgControl) state;
 whereas in your code its 
    @ContentChild(InputLabel) state; in FormField component. if you could please have a look at FormField component I posted in question and suggest should I use @ContentChild(NgControl) state; or should I have both @ContentChild(NgControl) state; and add another property @ContentChild(InputLabel) stateLabel;

Comment: I see. Sorry I missed that in Plunker. It should be `@Input() @HostBinding('attr.placeholder') label;` (both decorators on `label`)

Comment: As I mentioned at the end of my answer, I wasn't able to make this work. With  `NgControl` `state` was always undefined.

Comment: So, it seems the only option is to add both

@ContentChild(NgControl) state;
@ContentChild(InputPlaceholder) statePlaceholder;

One more thing, I replaced ngAfterContentChecked and ngOnChanges with ngAfterContentInit and it seems to be working fine. Any comment on this approach, isn't it better as its executed only once? and once the placeholder is added to the input we don't need to add it again.

Comment: You are right. While I built the Plunker something didn't work and I experimented with `ngOnContentChecked` and forgot to change it back.

Comment: Thank you Günter, you have always been very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome - keep these interesting questions coming ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could bind your label to "placeholder"

```
form-field label="First Name">
 <input ngControl="firstName" type="text" [attr.placeholder]="label">
</form-field>
```