# In angular2 can I query the existence of content children in order to modify my template based on their existence or lack?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Assuming I have a custom component that can be called as

```
<c-component>
  <c-title>title text</c-title>
  <c-help>help text</c-help>
</c-component>
```

or as just `<c-component></c-component>` or with either/only of the sub-compoenents.
And I want to present a completely different interface for c-component if there is not a sub-component vs. if there is....  Is there way I can query the existence of a child content element without inserting it?
e.g. in the c-content's template

```
<element if="c-help componenet exists">
  <various elements and stuff that can't go in the c-help directive/>
  <ng-content selector="c-help"></ng-content>
</element>
<element if="c-title component exists">
  <various elements and stuff that can't go in the c-help directive/>
  <ng-content selector="c-title"></ng-content>
</element>
<element if="c-title and c-help component don't exist">
  <various elements and stuff that can't go in the c-help directive/>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@ContentChild()` can be used for this:

```
@Comonent({
  ...
  template: `
  <div *ngIf="viewMode == 'simple'>
   <div>simple ui></div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="viewMode == 'advanced'>
   <div>advanced ui></div>
  </div>
`
})
class MyComponent {
  viewMode:string;
  @ContentChild(CTitle) cTitle:CTitle;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.viewMode = this.cTitle ? 'simple' : 'advanced';
  }
}
```

Comment: could you possibly update with an example where the subcomponent is standard native dom element?  e.g. what if title were just `<div class='title'>my title</div>`  Could I still pick that up with contentchild decorator? - my bad for the bad example, I know I showed them both as custom components...

Comment: With a native DOM element you would need to add a template variable like `<div #cTitle>`, then you could query  like `@ContentChild('cTitle') cTitle:CTitle;`. Without anything it would be a bit difficult. You could inject `ElementRef` to the wrapper element and search with `elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(...)` but that is rather bad style.

Comment: @Robert, another alternative (to `querySelector` or a local template variable) is a directive.  But I'm not a fan of that approach.  I discuss that approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36900712/215945

Comment: I also just answered a question with a similar problem with a Plunker example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752328/angular-2-contentchild-apply-html-attibutes